# manage focus in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

in my wpf app ,
i have two Views and two ViewModels,
when first ViewModel is binded to my ContentControl, the first View Loaded according to my ViewModel and one of the buttons on the first View has focused,
when second ViewModel binded to ContentControl,the second View loaded according to second View,
when i back and show first ViewModel and View, i want to focus old button that has focused,

some things like bellow:

```
    public static IInputElement focusedelement;
    public UCMainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus( focusedelement);
    }

    private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        focusedelement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `bool IsFocused` property in your view models and then data bind it to the [`UIElement.IsFocused` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused.aspx) of your relevant controls:

```
<Button IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused}" ... />
```

Then whenever you want to focus either one of them, just set the `IsFocused` property to `true` in your relevant view model:

```
IsFocused = true;
```

Note that if it is already `true`, you *may* need to first set it to `false` and then back to `true` for this to work.

Comment: thanks,You mean that i want to define IsFocused property in Vm for each button on View?i have several buttons in my view that one of them has focused when i leave that view and go to view 2,when i back to view 1,last button that has focused must get focuse.

Comment: button have not IsFocused attr.

Comment: No, I mean that you create one `IsFocused` property per view model. Only one `Button` can be focused when a view is loaded. You set this property on the `Button` that you want to have focus and set the property to `true` each time the view is loaded. As for your second comment, the [`Button` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) *does* have an `Isfocused` property.